# Supersized jQuery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, supersized

I have been working on customization of the Supersized jQuery plugin, its working absolutely fine. I have added  images in its slide functionality as an array with title. Now I want to make slow zoom in functionality in the images defined in slides.

Here's my current code:

```
jQuery(function($){
            $.supersized({
                // Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   2,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   500,        // Speed of transition
                new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   3,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                // Size & Position                         
                min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                thumbnail_navigation    :   1,          // Thumbnail navigation
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/1.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Test 1 title</p></div>},
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/2.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Integer turpis</p></div},
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/3.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Test 3 title</p></div>},
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/4.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Test title 4</p></div>},
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/5.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Test title 5</p></div>}
                                            ],

                    // Theme Options               
                    progress_bar            :   0,          // Timer for each slide                         
                    mouse_scrub             :   0


        });
        });
```

Comment: can you please explain the exact problem using jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: @Abhas Tnadon: Please see in the slides functionality above, i have added images like [{ image : 'images/background-slideshow/1.jpg'.... etc ] , i want these images to be loaded with slow zoom in effect, Please help

Comment: You have problem in passing arguments to the plugin. Close the quotes for title data.

Comment: @tandon: This is not the case of quotes, title everything is working fine, i want zoom in effects on the images, i.e. once the image gets load, it should slowly zoom in before sets off, and this step should be repeated for each image. Please understand me

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($){
            $.supersized({
                // Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   2,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   500,        // Speed of transition
                new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   3,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                // Size & Position                         
                min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                thumbnail_navigation    :   1,          // Thumbnail navigation
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/1.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Test 1 title</p></div>'},
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/2.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Integer turpis</p></div'},
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/3.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Test 3 title</p></div>'},
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/4.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Test title 4</p></div>'},
                                                {image : 'images/background-slideshow/5.jpg', title : '<div id="slidecountertop"><p>Test title 5</p></div>'}
                                            ],

                    // Theme Options               
                    progress_bar            :   0,          // Timer for each slide                         
                    mouse_scrub             :   0


        });
        });
```